# Qt creator embeded with Intel RealSense SDK cannot recognized the file

Tags: c++, qt, realsense

I am tring to use **Qt creator with Intel RealSense SDK 2.0** to create a demo in order to case the iamge in the UI interface, however, When I copy the code from the other Question's answer, I find that there is something wrong in my pro file, and here is the configuration of my project, and I use them in the windows systems, **and I can't open the UI even if the project can be qmake**. so I would like to hear your suggestion and critize, Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

```
    CONFIG += c++11
    
    # You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
    
    SOURCES += \
        CAMERA.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp
    
    HEADERS += \
        CAMERA.h \
        mainwindow.h
    
    FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
    
    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
    
    #RealSense SDK
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel RealSense SDK 2.0/include/"
    LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel RealSense SDK 2.0/bin/x86/realsense2.dll" #-realsense2 #-llibpxcmd #-llibpxcutilsmd  << Here is the error
    
    # opencv
    #INCLUDEPATH += E:\opencv3\include

    #LIBS += E:\opencv3\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_*.dll# opencv 动态链接
```

[the project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8xjR.png)

Here is the code links:
[code links](https://github.com/Hupengjie-coder/Qt-with-Intel-RealSense/blob/main/demo1.rar)

Comment: So, What is wrong with the `.pro` file?(As you saying `I find that there is something wrong in my pro file`)

Comment: OK, I find there is something wrong in the project, maybe it's my fault. But when you open my project, you will find the UI interface cannot be opened.